# Angular - Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever I try to create a new ticket, I get this error message:

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

This is my thread.service.ts where I have the AddTicket method I am using for creating a ticket:

```
 addTicket(
id: string,
heading: string,
user: string,
date: Date,
description: string,
likeCount: number,
timeLeft: number){
  const newTicket = new Threads
  (
    id,
    heading,
    user,
    new Date(date),
    description,
    likeCount,
    timeLeft
  );
  let generatedId: string;
  return this.http
  .post<{ name: string }>(
    'https://ionic-angular-a0570.firebaseio.com/all-tickets.json',
    {
      ...newTicket,
      id: Math.random().toString()
    }
  )
  .pipe(
    switchMap(resData => {
      generatedId = resData.name;
      return this.tickets;
    }),
    take(1),
    tap(tickets => {
      newTicket.id = generatedId;
      this._tickets.next(tickets.concat(newTicket));
    })
  );
}
```

And I am calling the method in new-thread.page.ts:

```
  onCreateTicket(){
this.threadService.addTicket(this.threads.id, this.heading, this.registerService.user, this.threadService.getDate(), this.description, +this.threadService.getLikes(), +12).subscribe();
```

This is my threads.model.ts if it helps:

```
export class Threads {
constructor(
    public id: string,
    public heading: string,
    public user: string,
    public date: Date,
    public description: string,
    public likeCount: number,
    public timeLeft: number
){}}
```

new-thread.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ThreadsService } from '../main/departmentforum/threads/threads.service';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RegisterService } from '../register/register.service';
import { Threads } from '../main/departmentforum/threads/threads.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-thread',
  templateUrl: './new-thread.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-thread.page.scss'],
})
export class NewThreadPage implements OnInit {
  heading: string;
  description: string;
  businessforum: string;
  departmentforum: string;
  threads: Threads;

  constructor(private navController: NavController, private threadService: ThreadsService, public registerService: RegisterService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onCreateTicket(){
    this.threadService.addTicket(this.threads.id, this.heading, this.registerService.user, this.threadService.getDate(), this.description, +this.threadService.getLikes(), +12).subscribe();
    this.navController.navigateBack('main/departmentforum/threads');
  }
}
```

thread.model.ts:

```
export class Threads {
constructor(
    public id: string,
    public heading: string,
    public user: string,
    public date: Date,
    public description: string,
    public likeCount: number,
    public timeLeft: number
){}}
```

Comment: Could you please say which line the error is thrown?

Comment: @MichaelD NewThreadPage.html:48 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at NewThreadPage.onCreateTicket (new-thread.page.ts:26)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (NewThreadPage.html:48)

Comment: It looks like `this.threads` in `onCreateTicket()` method is not initialized yet. Are you sure it is defined before the call?

Comment: @MichaelD I thought that this.threads comes from the model and would only be a template.. So I guess I haven't initialized it yet. How or where can I do so?

Comment: That I am not exactly sure of without taking a look at new-thread.page.ts or it's template.

Comment: I will edit my question, so everyone can see it!

Comment: @MichaelD You can have a look now

Comment: Ah, you see that `threads: Threads;` is declared but never initialized. So it is left undefined. That is why you get the error. But you also say that is supposed to be updated by the template. Could you please attach the template to the question too?

Comment: @MichaelD edited. But I don't mean that the template is updating threads.. I mean that threads.model.ts is used as a template for the tickets!

Comment: In any case, `this.threads` must be initialized with appropriate values before the method `onCreateTicket()` is called.

Comment: @MichaelD when I try to achieve this, this error comes up: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

Comment: How and where are you trying to do it?

Comment: In new-thread.page.ts I tried to give this.threads.id = "0"; in ngOnInit() just to test it

Comment: Now I do not understand what the problem is. It works for me in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbvujh).

Comment: @MichaelD look in the console

Comment: I overlooked one of the basic issues. `this.threads` is declared but never initialized. Please see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9p5hb1). I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`threads` variable in new-thread.page.ts is declared but never initialized. It should be initialized with some data. For eg.

```
threads: Threads = new Threads(
  '0', 
  '', 
  '', 
  new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 24*60*60*1000), 
  '', 
  null, 
  null
);
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9p5hb1)